Why does delphi change the transparent color of a bitmap?
I have a bitmap (see attachment) that's mostly white. So when transparency is turned on, it's a white pixel in the corner and white is the transparent color.
But when I use GetTransparentColor, I don't get white.
Looking at the code, for some reason Delphi adds a number to the color value, rendering it utterly useless as-is. Anyone know why that is ?



Probably the documentation will help you understand what the added "02" as most significant byte is returned. Look at https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Graphics.TColor. In your case, what is the value of FTranparentColor? It should be clDefault.

It is clDefault.
So from what I understand of this doc, TColor doesn't actually represent and RBG color but instead the closest matching RBG color in the designated palette ? If so, naming it TColor is wild lmao.

The 02 value (the highest order byte) is explained in Help for Vcl.Graphics.TColor
If the highest-order byte is zero, the color obtained is the closest matching color in the system palette. If the highest-order byte is one ($01 or 0x01), the color obtained is the closest matching color in the currently realized palette. If the highest-order byte is two ($02 or 0x02), the value is matched with the nearest color in the logical palette of the current device context. Note, this is an invention of Windows.

TColor does not have an alpha channel, so historically the high byte has been used to hold flags describing the color. For instance, the high bit (which the docs conveniently don't mention) indicates whether the color is RGB or a system color index. Guess they decided to add additional bit flags. I've never heard of this palette-matching flag before, and I doubt it's a Windows invention.
